# Only allowing one action and recording it in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a two part problem I am wanting to create a game of rock,paper scissors, that allows the user to play until he loses once against the computer. I will show the user a series of images (rock,paper,scirssors). I will then highlight the choice if the user clicks the image, then double click to confirm their choice to play against.

So I have this in my HTML that is shown after the user clicks play now:

```
<div id="playOptionsclassic" style="display: none">
    <img id="clickedRock" src="img/rock.jpg" onclick="playClassicWithRock()" dis/>
    <img id="clickedPaper" src="img/paper.jpg" onclick="playClassicWithPaper()"/>
    <img id="clickedScissors" src="img/scissors.jpg" onclick="playClassicWithScissors()" />
</div>
```

Then in my Jquery file I have:

```
$(function () {
    $("img").one("click",function() {
        $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");
    });
});
```

The problem I have here is the user can click more then one img right now. I want it to toggle the click, so if I click rock first, oh I change my mind I want scissors, unhighlight rock and highlight scissors. Or should i just make so it's one click and it is locked in?

How can I then pass a value of "rock","Paper" Scissors" into a javascript file to see if they beat the computer?

Comment: How do you determine which option the computer chooses?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).siblings().css('border','0px')` for change the colors of the clicked item and use `playClassicWithScissors(this)` "this" to pass your element to the function

```js
$(function () {
    $("img").on("click",function() {
      $(this).siblings().css('border','0px')
        $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");
    });
});

function playClassicWithRock(ele){
 alert($(ele).attr('id'));
}

function playClassicWithPaper(ele){
 alert($(ele).attr('id'));
 }
 
function playClassicWithScissors(ele){
 alert($(ele).attr('id'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="playOptionsclassic" style="display: block">
    <img id="clickedRock" src="img/rock.jpg" onclick="playClassicWithRock(this)" dis/>
    <img id="clickedPaper" src="img/paper.jpg" onclick="playClassicWithPaper(this)"/>
    <img id="clickedScissors" src="img/scissors.jpg" onclick="playClassicWithScissors(this)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that was wayyyy easier then everything I was trying. Quick question since I' on the track of over thinking it so far. How can I loop thie playOptions Classic as an option as long as they beat the computer

Comment: If this solves your problem. don't forget to mark it as the answer. For the second question can you give me the scenario? The question is not much clear to me.

Comment: You can loop with `$('#playOptionsclassic').each(function(index, element){  })`

Comment: Well I'm wanting to play Rock Paper Scissors with this code. So now I got the input from the user of what they want to play with. So I created 3 functions of what the user wants to play with. I call another function to get a computer's choice. Then if they win I want to ask the same question. Or say if they lose I want to disable the div tag I guess?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should prefer to use classes to individual CSS styles. It is generally easier (and much more robust, maintenance-wise) to add and strip a class, than to adjust the CSS properties.

An easy way to do this is to find a selector that matches all three images; then you can strip the "selected" class from all images (whether they have it or not) before you add it to the clicked image. jQuery makes this very easy.

The other typical way is to store the selection, so you can explicitly deselect that element before selecting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="playOptionsclassic" style="display: none">
    <img id="clickedRock" src="img/rock.jpg" class="game-opt-img" data-val="rock" dis/>
    <img id="clickedPaper" src="img/paper.jpg" class="game-opt-img" data-val="paper"/>
    <img id="clickedScissors" src="img/scissors.jpg" class="game-opt-img" data-val="scissors" />
</div>
```

Then in your javascript

```
$(function(){
    $(".game-opt-img").on("click", function() {
        $(".game-opt-img").off("click"); // remove all image's click event
        var val = $(this).data("val"); // get the value of the image that the user choose.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class in css called `.active` which adds the border to the image. So, when you click on an image, all you need to do is remove the `.active` class from all the images, and then add the `.active` to the image you clicked on.

This can be achieved by doing the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#playOptionsclassic div").on("click", function() {
    $("#playOptionsclassic div").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

/* Styles for example */
#playOptionsclassic div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="playOptionsclassic">
  <!-- Images replaced with divs for example -->
  <div id="clickedRock">Rock img</div>
  <div id="clickedPaper">Paper img</div>
  <div id="clickedScissors">Scissors img</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow another elegant solution. I like this one also! Is there a way to disable the boxes on clicking if say the user lost against the computer?

Comment: @Jona yes, there is. But it depends how you represent that the user has lost. Mostly likely you would have a `boolean` (true/false) value which indicates if the player has won (true) or lost (false). Eg: `var hasWon = false;`. Then, when you click the button, you can use an if statement to check if the player has won (ie when `hasWon == true`) to enable the boxes, `else` we can do nothing, thus, the boxs are essentially disabled

Answer (score 0):

First you can add a predefined class to each of the images and assign them a data attribute for what they represent (rock, paper, scissors) as follows:

```
<div id="playOptionsclassic" style="display: none">
    <img class="option" src="img/rock.jpg" data-option="rock"/>
    <img class="option" src="img/paper.jpg" data-option="paper"/>
    <img class="option" src="img/scissors.jpg" data-option="scissors"/>
</div>
```

Then you can create a class in CSS where you will have the style of the clicked image:

```
.active {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

And in your javascript, when the user single clicks one of the options, remove the `active` class from the others and add it to that image.

And when they double click, check if an option was selected and perform the necessary actions.

```
$(function() {
    $("img.option").on("click", function() {
        $("img.option.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $("img.option").on("dblclick", function() {
        var selectedOption = $("img.option.active");

        // Check if an option was selected.
        if (selectedOption.length) {
            // Save the name of the option (rock, paper or scissors) in a variable.
            var optionName = selectedOption.data("option");

            // Perform your action here.
        } else {
            alert("Please select an option.");
        }
    });
});
```